# SwiftUI: reading data from ObservableObject

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am new to SwiftUI and created a `Todo` model.  I then have a class that represents the container so that I can have an array of Todos and methods on it later on.  I made `TodoContainer` an `ObservableObject` and then observing it after instantiating it: `@ObservedObject var items = TodoContainer()`.
I am iterating through the list and expecting anytime I click the button, shouldn't it appear in the list since it's creating a new Todo each time and `allTodos` should have the array of all Todos?

```
import SwiftUI

struct Todo: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String;
    var priority: Int;
}

class TodoContainer: ObservableObject {
    @Published var allTodos = [Todo]();
}



struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var items = TodoContainer()
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Create New") {
            Todo(name: "New one", priority: Int.random(in: 1..<100))
        }
        List(items.allTodos, id: \.id){item in
            Text(item.name)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to add the object you have created to the array, `items.allTodos.append(…)`

Comment: Also, if it is the first instance of the object, you should use `@StateObject`, not `@ObservedObject`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the created todo to the view model's `allTodos`. Xcode may have shown you an error about an unused expression previously.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct Todo: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String;
    var priority: Int;
}

class TodoContainer: ObservableObject {
    @Published var allTodos = [Todo]();
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var items = TodoContainer()
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Create New") {
            let todo = Todo(name: "New one", priority: Int.random(in: 1..<100))
            items.allTodos.append(todo) // here
        }
        List(items.allTodos, id: \.id){item in
            Text(item.name)
        }
    }
}
```